# Multiple NSManagedObjectContext issues

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using a secondary managedobjectcontext in a serial GCD queue, using the same persistent store coordinator (and model). The problem I am having is the secondary managedobjectmodel appears to be empty - all fetch requests return nothing. I am using a sqlite store. I've tried doing the same thing on the main thread to no avail.

The code is pretty straightforward. The CoreDataUtility is a singleton, and the manageObjectContext member of the singleton is the other managed object context.

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[CoreDataUtility instance].managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

The fetch requests (I've tried several) are identical with the exception of the mom.

The secondary mom looks fine in the debugger - the properties you would expect to be the same in the primary mom are in fact the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the way I was loading the model. I don't have an explanation as to why this worked, but it did fix the problem. Maybe someone else can elucidate.

This code:

```
managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];
```

was replaced with this code:

```
NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mymodel" ofType:@"momd"];
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the persistent store coordinator returned from `[CoreDataUtility instance].managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator` is correct (have you checked this?), then this part at least should be fine.

I use a similar approach in my own app, and my code for creating the background context is exactly the same as for the main context. I expect the problem could be elsewhere.

Have you tried accessing the object in the main context, and then faulting the object into the other context using:

```
NSManagedObject *backgroundObject = [backgroundContext existingObjectWithID:object error:&error];
```

And seeing if the object is still valid?

Comment: If I get a valid object in the first context, and then attempt to retrieve its objectId I get null from the other context. I'm doing the exact same thing to create the mom - giving it the same persistent store coordinator.

Comment: On that operation, I get the following error. error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133000.)

Comment: Just to clarify - when you say "mom", I presume you mean the context, not the model? The model and store coordinator are shared by your contexts right?

Comment: By the way, the faulting error (Cocoa error 133000) represents the following: "`NSManagedObjectReferentialIntegrityError` - Error code to denote an attempt to fire a fault pointing to an object that does not exist. The store is accessible, but the object corresponding to the fault cannot be found." (from Apple docs). Are the data objects you are trying to fetch properly saved back to the model?

Comment: Yes, by mom I meant context (the mom is the same as well). Everything works great w/ the first context, but for some reason not the second. It's the same store coordinator (as verified in the debugger) and model. I also looked for any object and it appears to be completely empty.